# Angular 4 check if local storage is available in browser

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies, local-storage

Is it possible to make a check to see if local storage is available in the user's browser?  I have heavily used local storage and want to check if there are cases where I need to instead use cookies. I guess I can try to use localstorage and catch an error if it doesn't work and fallback to cookies, but is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an angular library to do this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/storage-available

The usage is pretty simple

```
import storageAvailable from 'storage-available'

if (storageAvailable('localStorage')) {
  // Yippee! We can use localStorage awesomeness 
}
else {
  // Too bad, no localStorage for us 
}
```